# Вывод списка городов при вводе в инпут

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, api

Как реализовать такой вот функционал: при вводе в `input` названия города идет список городов подходящих под него?

Например:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: зависит от того, откуда Вы берете данные... собственно, а откуда Вы их берете?

Comment: Гуглите autocomplete html JavaScript

Comment: суть заключается в том - я ввожу название города и мне выскакивают такие подсказки, далее кликаю на город и делаю запрос к базе или api

Comment: Ищите, есть готовые библиотеки под jQuery при том штук 5\6 минимум

Comment: а можете подсказать одну?)

Comment: jquery UI autocomplete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример, только с именами. Для решения задачи достаточно:

```js
function myFunction() {
    
    let input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    let filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    let ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    let li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (let i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        let a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        let txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
      
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().includes(filter)) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
//Tip: Remove toUpperCase() if you want to perform a case-sensitive search.
```

```css
#myInput {
    width: 95%; /* Full-width */
    font-size: 16px; /* Increase font-size */
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px; /* Add some padding */
    border: 1px solid #ddd; /* Add a grey border */
}
#myUL {
    /* Remove default list styling */
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 90%;
}

#myUL li a {
    border: 1px solid #ddd; /* Add a border to all links */
    margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
    background-color: #f6f6f6; /* Grey background color */
    padding: 12px; /* Add some padding */
    text-decoration: none; /* Remove default text underline */
    font-size: 18px; /* Increase the font-size */
    color: black; /* Add a black text color */
    display: block; /* Make it into a block element to fill the whole list */
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
    background-color: #eee; /* Add a hover effect to all links, except for headers */
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Это можно сделать штатными средствами без скриптов

```html
<input list="OWNER" value="" type="text" />
<datalist id="OWNER">
  <option>Москва
  <option>Санкт - Петербург
  <option>Иваново
  <option>Ярославль
</datalist>
```

Comment: если городов 10 штук, кастомный дизайн элементов не требуется, критерий фильтрации "содержит"